# How to know number of element in a DOM tree

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

I have `ul` , i want to know number of any of these list items(For example: Tomatoe's number is 3).

```
<li>Apple</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li>Tomato</li>
<li>Potato</li>
```

How can i do this?

UPD Also I am using vue js and v-for for list rendering.

UPD2 What i really want it is a get array of numbers of active lists when i selected them.

I did this like that:

```
let selectedlist = document.getElementsByClassName('selected')
  let list = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
  this.indexOfSelectedLists = [] // array that i need
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < selectedlist.length; j++) { // because findIndex() isnt supported
      list[i].innerHTML === selectedlist[j].innerHTML
        ? this.indexOfSelectedLists.push(i)
        : null
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Would probably help if you clarify what you want. People are giving DOM based answers, which you really wouldn't want to do in Vue.

Comment: @Bert updated with pic and my decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to get the elements, and use `forEach()` to display the elements along with their indexes (numbers):

```
var list = document.getElementById("myList");
var elements = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll("li"));

elements.forEach(function(li, index) {
  console.log(li.innerText + " is number " + (index + 1));
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var list = document.getElementById("myList");
var elements = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll("li"));

elements.forEach(function(li, index) {
  console.log(li.innerText + " is number " + (index + 1));
});
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Tomato</li>
  <li>Potato</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

No need any javascript code. [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) can handle what you want.

If you define your `v-for` like this: `<li v-for="(fruit, index) in fruits">`, `index` gives you the index number and you can print it out as `{{ index + 1 }}`

[an example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#example-1) from the documentation website.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of any element, please check the example.

```js
var findIndex = "Tomato";
$("ul li").each(function(index, item) {
  if($(item).text() == findIndex){
    console.log("Index of " + findIndex + " is: " + (index + 1));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Tomato</li>
  <li>Potato</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're trying to render the index in your `v-for` loop, you could use `v-for="(item, index) of items"` and then access `{{index}}`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [ 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Tomato', 'Potato' ],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) of items">{{index}} - {{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

<sup>See [Vue's Guide for *List Rendering*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)</sup>